# Extract Python subprocess.CalledProcessError argument list

Tags: python, subprocess

Following is the code snippet from our code base

```
# global library function
def check_call_noout(params, acceptable_exit_codes = (0,), shellCommand=False):
    FNULL = open('/dev/null', 'w')
    sts = 1
    try:
        if shellCommand:
            p = subprocess.Popen(params, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL,shell=True)
        else:
            p = subprocess.Popen(params, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
        sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
    except:
        raise
    finally:
       FNULL.close()
       exit_code = sts >> 8
       if exit_code not in acceptable_exit_codes:
           raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, params)

# driver code
try:
    cmd = ["/bin/tar", "--acls", "--selinux", "--xattrs", "-czf a.tar.gz", "./a.xml", "--exclude","\"lost+found\""]
    check_call_noout(cmd,(0,1),False)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output, e.returncode
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__name__, e)
```

I want to print the params argument value passed into **subprocess.CalledProcessError** object which is raised inside the library function and caught in my driver code.

However, I cannot change anything in the library function **check_call_noout()**

Comment: Are you looking for [`CalledProcessError.cmd`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError.cmd)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, getting the `__dict__` attribute of `subprocess.CalledProcessError` class would do:

```
try:
    subprocess.run([...], check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.__dict__)
```

You can also use `vars` function which will call `__dict__` internally:

```
try:
    subprocess.run([...], check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(vars(e))
```